# How do I use Promise.all to make it work?

Tags: node.js, post, get, promise, ejs

My main purpose is to make this function work:

*Whenever users click the "likes" button or "dislikes" button, it will post new data to server, then the server is supposed to update both of number of "likes" and "dislikes" in database. After that, it will redirect to another URL to get the previous page with new updated number of "likes" and "dislikes".*

During the process, because of JS's asynchronous effect, I decide to use Promise.all. But I was stuck in that part (marked by 3 question marks in my code). Could anybody help me to revise it or give me any better suggestion?

Here is my Node.js codes:

```
app.post("/searchresult/comments/likes", function(req, res) {
var likes = req.body.likes;
var dislikes = req.body.dislikes;
var Text = req.body.text;
var Arr = [likes, dislikes];

Promise.all(Arr.map(function (attribute) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        comments.update({text: Text}, {$set: {???: attribute}}, function(err){
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log("Update successfully!");
                resolve(comments);
            }
        });
}).then(function(r){
    console.log("DONE!");
    res.redirect("/searchresult");
})
}));
});
```

//*************************************************  Update!  ************************************************//

Thanks so much to Ganesh Karewad, James and dasfdsa. I have made it work properly.

Comment: So this doesn't look like this question is related to `Promise.all` at all, more MongoDB...

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I mean if I don't use `Promise.all` (set two functions apart---- one for "likes", another for "dislike"), the `redirect` always runs before updating my database.

Comment: so really the issue is you are unsure as to what attribute you need to be updating because `Arr` is not specific? The question really isn't clear in that regard but I understand what the problem is now. I think @GaneshKarewad's answer looks the most promising.

Comment: Sorry for my unclear description. I used Ganesh's codes and it worked properly. Anyway, thanks for your comment.

Comment: please don't bundle more questions on top of an existing question - if you have a different problem you should open a new question. The purpose of the site is to help others, having lots of questions under a misleading headline won't help anyone. Your new update completely negates the answer you've accepted.

Comment: I am so sorry. I will recover it to my previous question and open a new question.

Comment: no problem, I can see from your rep you are obviously new to the site and probably aren't aware of the rules - you should read the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for some tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use array of object instead of direct values like
     var Arr = [{key:'likes',value:likes},{key:'dislikes',value:dislikes}];

```
 app.post("/searchresult/comments/likes", function(req, res) {
    var likes = req.body.likes;
    var dislikes = req.body.dislikes;
    var Text = req.body.text;
    var Arr = [{key:'likes',value:likes},{key:'dislikes',value:dislikes}];

    Promise.all(Arr.map(function (attribute) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        comments.update({text: Text}, {$set: {attribute.key: attribute.value}}, 
         function(err){
            if (err) {
             // reject or log error according to need
                console.log(err);
             // reject(err);
            } else {
                console.log("Update successfully!");
                resolve(comments);
             }
          });
      }).then(function(r){
       console.log("DONE!");
       res.redirect("/searchresult");
      }).catch(function(err){
      // reject or log error according to need
      // console.log(err);
       reject(err);
      })
     }));
    });
```

Comment: What happens when this code gets a database error from `comments.update()`?  It seems like it would never resolve or reject the promise that is being created.  That can't be correct.

Comment: Also, wouldn't one want to use the promise interface built into the database rather than make your own?

Comment: behaviour of comments.update is unknown , answer was specific for question and not a generic. and yes there should be error handling

Comment: It's pretty simple.  When you post code in an answer, you should correct things that are clearly wrong.  At least change `console.log(err)` to `reject(err)`.  I'm not sure why you won't make a simple edit to improve your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry misread the Q.
You can prepare array beforehand.

```
let likeObj = {like:req.body.likes};
let dislikeObj = {dislike:req.body.dislikes};

let Arr = [likeObj, dislikeObj];

Promise.all(Arr.map(function (attribute) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        comments.update({text: Text}, {$inc: attribute}, function(err){
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log("Update successfully!");
                resolve(comments);
            }
        });
})
```

Comment: This would increment the value rather than set it.

Comment: I thought this is what op is looking for